# How do I overlay a Html video with content that has a background image?

Tags: css, html5-video

Here is a plunker for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/41sdho4w/

```
<div>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/f890SC1schE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

  video, iframe {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZNgk.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 4.9% 17.5% 7.8%;
  }
```

I would like to overlay the video inside the laptop (not the whole video tag) with some content (img). How would I go about that?

Ultimately, when the overlay is clicked, the video would reveal itself and start playing. Bonus points for a solution that keeps this in mind!

Answer (score -1):

http://zerosixthree.se/create-a-responsive-header-video-with-graceful-degradation/

This tutorial answers your question....

Comment: He wants the video to stay inside the laptop.